# Не отправляется текс через FormData

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, fetch

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.set("photo", file);
formData.set("name", "Петя");
formData.set("email", "petya@mail.ru");
formData.set("password", "123123");
    
fetch(
  "/api/profile", {
    method: "PUT",
    body: formData
});

[HttpPut]
public void Put(IFormFile photo, string name, string email, string password)
{
  //TODO: some code
}
```

Дело в том, что отправляются только файлы, а текст нет. Как через FormData отправить текст?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

[HttpPut]
public void Put([FromForm] UserInfo info)
{
    //TODO: some code
}
```

Если у кого-то есть еще идеи - предлагайте.